# Two dataobject managed in one gridfied with orderable columns. Silverstripe 3.1

Tags: silverstripe

I'm working with Silverstripe 3.1

I would like manage in one admin model page two dataobject. Here is my first DataObject :

```
class Interview extends DataObject
{
    private static $db = array(
        'Name'          => 'Varchar(255)',
        'LieuExercice'  => 'Varchar(255)',
        'Presentation'  => 'Text',
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Photo'     => 'Image'
    );

    private static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'Journal'   => 'Journal'
    );

    // Change the label in datagrid
    private static $field_labels = array(
        'NameAndExercice' => 'Nom de la personne interviewée',
        'LieuExercice' => 'Lieu d\'exercice'
    );
    public function getNameAndExercice(){
        return  new LiteralField('NameAndExercice', $this->Name  . ' <em style=\'font-size:11px\'>('.$this->LieuExercice.')</em>');
    }

    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'NameAndExercice',
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = FieldList::create(TabSet::create('Root'));
        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Contenu', TextField::create('Name', 'Nom de la personne interviewée'));
        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Contenu', TextField::create('LieuExercice', 'Lieu d\'exercice')->setDescription('Lieu d\'exercice de la personne'));
        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Contenu', TextareaField::create('Presentation', 'Présentation')->setDescription('Courte présentation de la personne'));
        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Contenu', $photo = UploadField::create('Photo', 'Portrait de la personne interviewée')->setDescription('Fichier image du portrait de la personne'));

        //Fields configuration
        $photo->getValidator()->setAllowedExtensions(array('png', 'jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg'));
        $photo->setFolderName('interview-photos');

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

And here is my 2nd DataObject :

```
class Article extends DataObject
{
    private static $db = array(
        'Title'          => 'Varchar(255)',

    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Photo'     => 'Image'
    );

    private static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'Journal'   => 'Journal'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = FieldList::create(TabSet::create('Root'));

        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Contenu', TextField::create('Title', 'Titre de l\'article'));

        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Contenu', $photo = UploadField::create('Photo', 'Portrait de la personne interviewée')->setDescription('Fichier image du portrait de la personne'));

        //Fields configuration
        $photo->getValidator()->setAllowedExtensions(array('png', 'jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg'));
        $photo->setFolderName('interview-photos');

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Finally, I have a 'parent' dataObject witch contain some Interviews and Article :

```
class Journal extends DataObject
{
    private static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Varchar',
        'DatePublication'   => 'Date'
    );
    private static $has_one = array(
        'Couverture'        => 'Image'
    );
    private static $many_many = array(
        'Interviews'    => 'Interview',
        'Articles'      => 'Article',
    );
    private static $many_many_extraFields = array(
        'Interviews' => array(
            'SorterField' => 'Int',
        ),
        'Articles' => array(
            'SorterField' => 'Int',
        ),
    );

    public function getCMSFields(){
            $fields = FieldList::create(TabSet::create('Root'));

            $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main', array(
                $titleField = TextField::create('Title', 'Titre / Numéro du journal'),
                $datePublicationField = DateField::create('DatePublication', 'Date de publication'),
                $uploadField = UploadField::create('Couverture', 'Couverture du journal')

            ));


            if($this->ID){
                $fields->insertAfter(
                    new Tab('Content', 'Contenu du journal'),
                    'Main'
                );

                //$buttonCreateMultiClass = new GridFieldAddNewMultiClass();
                //$buttonCreateMultiClass->setClasses(array('Interviews', 'Article'));

                $config = GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create();
                $config->addComponent(new GridFieldOrderableRows('SorterField'));

                $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Content', GridField::create(
                    'Interviewsz',
                    'Contenu de ce journal',
                    $this->getManyManyComponents('Interviews')->sort('SorterField'),
                    $config
                ));
            }

            // Fields configuration
            $datePublicationField->setConfig ('showcalendar', true);
            $uploadField->getValidator()->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'jpeg'));
            $uploadField->setFolderName('journals-couvertures');
            return $fields;

    }
}
```

I would like in a model admin page of Journal:
- Create new Journal : OK, done
- Link one or more interview to this Journal
- Link one or more article to this Journal
- Manage the order of article and interview inside the journal

How do this ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just to clarify - is the problem here that Interviews and Articles are ordered as one intermingled list? So you couldn't just have two separate gridfields, each independently orderable?

Comment: Yes ! It's the problem. Interviews and Articles belongs to Journal. Like a newspaper. I have to manage the order.

Comment: Didn't we chat about that some days ago in IRC? You need to subclass both DataObjects from one, then you can manage the sort order in one Gridfield. Or you need some other dataobject in between for creating the relations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would give both articles and interviews a common parent class and put both in one gridfield (as wmk suggested in the comments). I'd also suggest you use the GridFieldAddMultiClass component from this extension: https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions so that a user can select whether he/she wants to add an Interview or an Article. Something like the following:

```
class Journal extends DataObject {
    private static $has_many = ['ContentItems' => 'ContentItem'];
}

class ContentItem extends DataObject {
    private static $db => ['Sort' => 'Int'];
    private static $has_one => ['Journal' => 'Journal'];
}

class Article extends ContentItem {}
class Interview extends ContentItem {}
```

Then you build your single GridView off the Journal.ContentItems() relationship.